# If user enters specific text into form, take them to certain page on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a website where the user can learn about web or game design, and there's a form on the index asking which they prefer to learn. The only part of my script that's working is that is alerts them they didn't choose if they left the form blank and submitted. Here's the code:

JS:

```
function validateForm() {
var x=document.forms["form1"]["lesson"].value;
if (x === "web design") {
location.href="web.html";
} else if(x === "game design") {
    location.href="game.html";
} else {
    alert("You didn't choose. You will remain on the home page.");
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            Would you rather learn web design <i>or</i> game design?:      <input type="text" name="lesson">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: So what is the problem here. Not sure about your issue. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Instead of var x=document.forms["form1"]["lesson"].value; can you try document.getElementsByName("lesson").value

Comment: If i use that how would a then grab the info they entered? (new to javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[If I understand your problem correct:] You should refer to `form[0]` and also set the `<form>`'s `action`-property instead of changing the location. If not, why bother using a form anyway? I would do the following imho more flexible approach instead :

```js
function validateForm() {
    var val=document.forms[0]['lesson'].value;
    switch (val) {
        case 'web design' :
            document.forms[0].action="web.html";
            break;
        case 'game design' : 
            document.forms[0].action="game.html";
            break;
        default : 
            alert("You didn't choose. You will remain on the home page.");
            return false;
            break;
    }
}
```

and change the markup to

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm();">
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, guess you mean on the form? Yes, but onclick in the submit button work as well. Good point.

Comment: I bring it up because you went out of your way to instruct the OP to use an `onclick` handler on the submit button instead, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: didnt see the forest for the trees :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather suggest you to move on to jQuery. It is easy to use and reduces the code typing fatigue. So, if you'd use jQuery, your form would look like:

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
            Would you rather learn web design <i>or</i> game design?:      <input type="text" id="lesson">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

and your jQuery would be like:

```
$(function()
{
  $('#form1').on('submit',function()
 {
  if($('#lesson').trim().val()=="web design")
   location.href="web.html";
  if($('#lesson').trim().val()=="game design")
   location.href="game .html";
  else
  {
   alert("You didn't choose. You will remain on the home page.");
  return false;
  }
});
});
```

and do not forget to include the jquery script file in head part of your html document. Go [here](http://jquery.com/download/) for the download link.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't redirect the user when they enter the text.

Comment: Did you add the jquery file?

Answer (score 0):

> Try like this

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        Would you rather learn web design <i>or</i> game design?:<input type="text" name="lesson" id="lesson">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

> JS

```
function validateForm() {
var x = document.getElementById('lesson').value;
if (x === "web design") {
    location.href = "web.html";
}

else if (x === "game design") {
    location.href = "game.html";
}
else {
    alert("You didn't choose. You will remain on the home page.");
}}
```